# Find distance between two points (lat/long)

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

I am completely new to Android development. I have thousands of places with their latitude/longitude in MySQL. What I am trying to learn is, how do I find out closest 10 places based on the device location.

I am aware about MySQL GeoSpatial index, using which I can find closest locations with respect to device co-ordinates. But that wouldn't be the actual distance user has to travel, right? the actual route may be longer than the displacement.

I can use Google Distance Matrix API For getting distance based on the actual route, but how and what points would I pass to Google API? If I pass 1 origin and 10 destinations, out of which say 8 are 200m away and 2 are way longer, I would miss other 2 entries that should have been shown in the listing.

Please suggest what is the better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/). It shows the nearest locations and retrieves the address of the nearest place in the list

Without using this you will need to use more  mathematical calculations which would be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

there is no easy solution in your case. the best suggestion i can think of is for you to provide queries for more than 10 closest points, lets say 15 and get the 10 best answers out of these 15 results. you would need to optimize the number of requests (maybe 12 or 17 would be enough) for which u get best results. the larger the number of requests the better the probability of accurate results but the lower the performance. so u need to find a proper balance. other than that i cant think of any other reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You rarely base these things on actual route.  I have a consumer GPS device-  the route it gives me is always a few miles more than the distance it lists in the POI screen, because its just doing direct line distance there.  Actually calculating routes would be extremely expensive-  notice it takes a few seconds to do a single route lookup when you hit the navigate button on google maps.  So I'd say just use the co-ordinates, its what everyone else does.